# Any replacement for deprecated `jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation` method

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, avfoundation

Four years ago, I used this [type method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturestillimageoutput/1388131-jpegstillimagensdatarepresentati) that is now deprecated (as well as its `AVCaptureStillImageOutput` class).

```
func jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(_ jpegSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer) -> Data? { }

let data = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(jpegBuffer)
```

The `AVCapturePhotoOutput` class designed to replace the `AVCaptureStillImageOutput` class does not have the required method in its arsenal. What method should I use instead of deprecated one?

Comment: Looking at the docs, it seems you need to implement the [photoOutput(_:didFinishProcessingPhoto:error:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephotocapturedelegate/2873949-photooutput) method of `AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate` if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you indeed need to implement `AVCapturePhotoOutput`, something like (very rough idea of implementation, follow [Apple's guide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/photo_capture/capturing_still_and_live_photos) instead):

```
class PhotoCapturer {
    var photoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
    
    func takePhoto() {
        let photoSettings: AVCapturePhotoSettings = {
            let processedFormat: [String: Any] = [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.jpeg]
            return AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: processedFormat)
        }()
        photoOutput.capturePhoto(with: photoSettings, delegate: self)
    }
}
```

As you notice, we also need to implement the `AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate` delegate, like so:

```
extension PhotoCapturer: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {

    /// Receives this message whenever a captured image is ready
    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
```

When the image is taken, this method will receive it in the `AVCapturePhoto` format. From here you have a variety of options, depending on your needs:

- [.fileDataRepresentation()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephoto/2873919-filedatarepresentation) - a flat data representation suitable for saving in file. Since we requested the `jpeg` format above, the data will represent the jpeg as well.
- [.cgImageRepresentation()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephoto/2873963-cgimagerepresentation) - a `CGImage` representation. Good for if you want to show or edit the image. Not quite JPEG, but JPEG-convertable using `UIImage(cgImage: ...).jpegData(compressionQuality:...)`
- Finally, there's [pixelBuffer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephoto/2873914-pixelbuffer), which returns you to a familiar `PixelBuffer` format, if you wish to reuse some parts of your existing processing.